# Creating Github Organization using graphql

Tags: github, graphql, postman, github-api, github-graphql

I tried below code to create organization using my github account getting error

`mutation { createOrganization(input: { login: "besttestzzzz", admin: true }) { organization { id login } } }`

`{ "input": { "admin": [ "testgithubaccount" ],`

```
"clientMutationId": "",
"login": "testgithubaccount"
```

`} }`

I got errors view the below image.

[image: view the below image]

Answer (score 0):

GitHub's GraphQL API does not provide direct endpoints to create organizations. Organization creation is typically done through the GitHub web interface or using the REST API.

```
Here's how you can use rest API:

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '{
  "login": "new-org",
  "profile_name": "New Organization",
  "admin": "your-username"
}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can!

```
gh api graphql -f query='
    mutation NeueOrg{
        createEnterpriseOrganization(
            input: { adminLogins: ["MyGH_Account"], billingEmail:"github@exsample.de", 
                enterpriseId: "MREFOkVudGVydHJpc2UxMzM5", login: "NeueOrg", profileName: "Neue Org"
            }
        )
        {enterprise {
            id
        }
    }
}'
```